# How to do a barplot from data frame

Tags: r

I have this data frame named "dt" (which contains 100 individuals but cut it down to 8) and have to do a barplot of the salary counts in 5 intervals (so let's say by=20,000)

```
     ID     Salary   Bonus
   --------------------------
1:   1     100000    57
2:   2      86000    66
3:   3      17000    12
4:   6      50500    37
5:   9      35000    26
6:   10     45000    21
7:   11     95000    54
8:   12    100000    58
```

How do I do it with barplot()? This is what I tried to do:

> barplot(cut(dt$Salary,c(seq(1,max(dt$Salary),by=20000))))

but it says that "height" needs to be a vector or a matrix.

Comment: You can use `cut` to create the interval.  Can you show the `dput` of the example.  I think the 'Salary' column is not `numeric` because of `,`

Comment: You may need `cut(dt$Salary, breaks = 5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `cut` the 'Salary' with `breaks` mentioned as 5, get the frequency count with `table` and plot with `barplot`

```
barplot(table(cut(df1$Salary, breaks = 5)))
```

---

Or specify the `min` and `max` in `seq` to get a sequence `by` 20000

```
barplot(table(cut(df1$Salary, 
     breaks = seq(min(df1$Salary)- 100, max(df1$Salary) + 100, by = 20000))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), Salary = c(100000L, 
86000L, 17000L, 50500L, 35000L, 45000L, 95000L, 100000L), Bonus = c(57L, 
66L, 12L, 37L, 26L, 21L, 54L, 58L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:", "7:", "8:"))
```